# scipy: Which distributions have a "fit" function implemented?

Tags: python, scipy, introspection

scipy has over a hundred distributions in their stats module, but not all them have a "fit" function implemented.  Is there a way to check which distributions have it and which don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
def distswith(fn='fit'):
    """prints out distributions with '.fit' methods. 
    where any class with a '._pdf' method is considered a distribution
    """
    import scipy.stats
    for fn in dir(scipy.stats):
        fns=eval('dir(scipy.stats.'+fn+')')
        if '_pdf' in fns and 'fit' in fns: 
            print fn
```

EDIT: looks to me like all 86 do.

Comment: discrete distributions have a .pmf method and not a pdf method. None of the discrete distributions have a fit method, all of the continuous distributions do have a fit method, but it is not working for all distributions without good defaults.